# How can I remove duplicate id's based on the earliest datetime and then find the intersection of this list and another based on the same datetime?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

So I have the following query

```
select * from sval where fid = 4044 and val = 'True';
```

The output of the above is:

**sval table**

```
id      fid               timestamp              val 
 1      4044        2019-01-22 00:00:00.000     True
 2      4044        2020-02-22 00:00:00.000     True 
 3      4044        2023-02-02 00:00:00.000     True 
 1      4044        2020-05-28 00:00:00.000     True
 4      4044        2023-05-03 00:00:00.000     True
 ....
```

I have another query:

```
select * from ival where fid = 3994 and val=0
```

The result of the query is:

**ival table**

```
id      fid                timestamp            val 
 1      3994        2019-01-22 00:00:00.000      0
 2      3994        2020-02-22 00:00:00.000      0 
 3      3994        2023-02-02 00:00:00.000      0 
 1      3994        2020-05-28 00:00:00.000      0
 4      3994        2023-05-03 00:00:00.000      0
```

I am trying to achieve 2 things:

1. I need to filter the first table to remove duplicates `id`'s and only keep the 'earliest' `id`, i.e. the one with the earliest timestamp.
2. From this filtered list, I need to return a list of all the `id`'s  in the `ival` table that have the SAME `timestamp` as the result of 1)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the row with the least value in a group, you'll want to use `column = MIN(column) OVER(PARTITION BY groupingexpression)` somewhere in the process.

```
with 
sval (
    id
  , fid
  , timestamp
  , val
) as (
        select  1, 4044, cast('2019-01-22 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 'True'
  union select  2, 4044, cast('2020-02-22 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 'True'
  union select  3, 4044, cast('2023-02-02 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 'True'
  union select  1, 4044, cast('2020-05-28 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 'True'
  union select  4, 4044, cast('2023-05-03 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 'True'
),
ival (
    id
  , fid
  , timestamp
  , val
) as (
        select 1, 3994, cast('2019-01-22 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 0
  union select 2, 3994, cast('2020-02-22 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 0
  union select 3, 3994, cast('2023-02-02 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 0
  union select 1, 3994, cast('2020-05-28 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 0
  union select 4, 3994, cast('2023-05-03 00:00:00.000' as timestamp), 0
),
svalFiltered as (
  select id
  , fid
  , timestamp
  , val
  , min(timestamp) over (partition by id) as timestampMin
  from sval
)

select 
  s.id
, s.fid
, s.timestamp
, s.val
, i.id as iid
, i.fid as ifid
, i.val as ival
from svalFiltered s
  inner join ival i on i.timestamp = s.timestamp

where s.timestamp = s.timestampMin
```

Comment: Hi dougp, in my database there are hundreds of thousands of rows, so I won't be able to write it all out like that - do you know if there is a generic way to write it?

Comment: Write it out like what?  Are you complaining that I included the data from your question in a manner that enables the example to be run as-is?  sval and ival are CTEs that reproduce the input data you provided.  In your actual solution, replace them with your initial queries or omit them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

1. *Filter the first table to keep only the earliest id for each fid.*

Use a common table expression (CTE) along with the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign a row number based on the timestamp for each fid. From ths, we can select the rows with row numbrs equal to 1 to get the earliest id for each fid.

```sql
WITH RankedSval AS (
    SELECT 
        id, fid, timestamp, val,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fid ORDER BY timestamp) AS rn
    FROM sval
)
SELECT id, fid, timestamp, val
FROM RankedSval
WHERE rn = 1;
```

2. *Return a list of all the id's in the ival table with the same timestamp as the result of Task 1.*

We use the same approach as before, but we also join it with the ival table to get the ids with the same timestamps.

```
WITH RankedSval AS (
    SELECT 
        id, fid, timestamp, val,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fid ORDER BY timestamp) AS rn
    FROM sval
)
SELECT DISTINCT RankedSval.id as sval_id, ival.id as ival_id, ival.timestamp
FROM ival
JOIN RankedSval ON ival.timestamp = RankedSval.timestamp
WHERE RankedSval.rn = 1;
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NWUN3T3L)

Comment: Thanks abstract_monk, are you able to tweak the first query, so that it filter for only where `fid=4044`  and `val=True`? (since in my real database there are many many different `fid` values, but I only want the ones with `fid=4044`.

And for the second query where `fid = 3994` and `val=0`?

Comment: Also, if I have hundreds of thousands of rows, I think the above will be very very slow?